# Ultra fast find and replace in +10000 rows

Tags: excel, vba

```
With Workbooks("Test.xlsm")

.Worksheets("Test").Cells.Replace What:=" | ", Replacement:="||", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

.Worksheets("Test").Select
End With
```

Im using this part below over 300 times with different combinations to find and replace, but it takes really long to complete, is there a faster way to do this?

```
.Worksheets("Test").Cells.Replace What:=" | ", Replacement:="||", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```

Comment: You can drop the `.Worksheets("Test").Select`. Probably turn off screen updating too. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Comment: Will try that, anything code wise I can do to make it faster?

Comment: You could try not do do the whole sheet, just the relevant range?

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: You could load the whole thing into an array, modify the array and paste that to a range instead of tons of sheet changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "different combinations"?

Comment: I have changed it a little bit according to the advice above. Seems to be a lot faster now, is there any page where I can see how to do it in an array? (I think this is the fastest method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out something like the below. You can store the entire range into an array, and loop over a map of replacements you need.

It's pretty basic just to give you the gist, but you may need to adjust case sensitivity of the search/replace for example.

This method should be pretty fast as it should reduce the amount of workbook interactions being done. I profiled this briefly on my machine, and it's doing the replace operation on 420,000 cells in about 1.5 seconds.

---

Edit

Added options for case sensitivity for the `Dictionary` and the `Instr` method.

```
Option Explicit

'Add each replacement value you want in here, or could read in from a range
Public Function GetReplacements() As Object
    Set GetReplacements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Key is the value you are looking
    'The Value is the replacement
    With GetReplacements
        .CompareMode = 1 '1 = TextCompare (Case Insensitive), 0 = BinaryCompare (Case Sensitive)
        .Add " | ", "||"
        .Add "b", "Something New"
        .Add "c", "Something New"
        .Add "d", "Something New"
        .Add "Something Else", "ABCD"
    End With
    
End Function

Public Sub ReplaceValues(ByVal RangeToSearch As Range, ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod)
    
    Dim cellValues As Variant
    cellValues = RangeToSearch.Value2
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Replacements As Object
    Dim Replacement As Variant
    
    Set Replacements = GetReplacements()
    
    'Iterate the array
    For i = LBound(cellValues) To UBound(cellValues)
        
        For j = LBound(cellValues, 2) To UBound(cellValues, 2)
            
            For Each Replacement In Replacements
                'Check if the string contains what we are looking for, then replace
                If InStr(1, cellValues(i, j), Replacement, CompareMethod) > 0 Then
                    cellValues(i, j) = Replace(cellValues(i, j), Replacement, Replacements.Item(Replacement))
                End If
            Next
        
        Next
        
    Next
    
    RangeToSearch = cellValues
    
End Sub

'Run from here
Public Sub CallMe()
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer()
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C140000")
    
    ReplaceValues SearchRange, VbTextCompare
    Debug.Print Timer() - t
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this will replace any formulas in the search range with their values, which may or may not be ok for the OP

Comment: Aah damn just spend 2 hours putting everything in arrays haha, gonna try this above!

Comment: @Ryan Wildry can you add an example if I want to use case sensitivity?

Comment: Atm, I'm getting: Error 457 - 'this key is already associated with an element in this collection, I need to use lowercase and uppercase words even if they are the same.

Comment: Nvm, I got it I added Option Compare Text in the module. Let me test this out now!

Comment: Is it possible to allow double keys? It says its double but its really not for example: 
.Add " Test", "Test"

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean. You can have the same Key and Value, but you can't have the same Key.

Comment: Is there a way to have the same key?